# Camera Control variable in Unity?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a script that controls camera. Here is the script:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
public GameObject player;
private Vector3 offset;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    offset = transform.position - player.transform.position;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void LateUpdate()
{
    transform.position = player.transform.position + offset;
}
```

}

I drag and drop script to camera, it it works. But I have not added any variable for camera, so unable to understand how it is controlling camera?

e.g. player.transform.position >> This is position of player.

but transform.position >> this is controlling the camera. How? Shouldn't it be something like camera.transform.position?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

transform.position is the transform.position of the game object to which the script is attached.

Here the script is attached to the Camera game object, so transform.position is the position of the Camera game object.